# Дополнение подсветки синтаксиса языка в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Здравствуйте, а возможно ли дополнить подсветку синтаксиса в Notepad++, например добавить к JS функции JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно. Как это сделать не плохо описано на [Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144830/)

Comment: Читал эту статью, и ту на которую ссылался автор поста, но там везде создают свой синтаксис. А мне бы хотелось расширить уже готовый JS

Comment: Тут два варианта: найти в сети файлик с синтаксисом, либо написать его самому с учётом нативного javascript и jQuery.

Comment: @Jarry Roxwell скопируйте XML для JavaScript (находится в папке API) и добавляйте в него методы и ключевые слова jQuery. Необходимо только отсортировать затем по алфавиту. После завершения редактирования заменитель оригинальный файл.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить собственные слова используя меню

**Опции** -> **Определение стилей...**.

В открывшемся окне можно добавлять свои ключевые слова предварительно выбрав необходимый синтаксис (например, JS) из списка.