# Notepad++: добавить в имеющиеся стили (Javascript) дополнительную логику подсветки

Tags: css, синтаксис, notepad++

подскажите пожалуйста, как в Notepad  к имеющемуся стилю (Javascript) добавить обработку дополнительных конструкций

в сети нашел описание как сделать полностью свой стиль, но мне этого не надо

[Дополнение подсветки синтаксиса языка в Notepad++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570744/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-notepad)

вот тут советуют импортировать стиль и добавить свои ключевые слова, но мне нужны не слова, а некоторые конструкции типа ${тут текст}

импортировать стиль из C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\APIs тоже ничего не получилось - выдается ошибка, да и в javascript.xml только ключевые слова

Answer (score 0):

Опции - Определение стилей. Там можно свои переменные задавать, внизу поля для этого предназначенные.

Comment: вот в упор не вижу :( выбираю "Определение стилей" и "Javascript" - в итоге есть несколько установленных стилей "INSTRUCT WORD, ..., COMMENT DOC KEYWORD", но не вижу где свой добавить или где посмотреть, какие настройки (не про цвет и шрифт, а про условия стандартных стилей) есть

Comment: Вот здесь задаются собственные переменные http://prntscr.com/ixe2sj

Comment: Э.. я имел в виду несколько другое - мне надо добавить свой стиль для конструкции ${тут текст}, т.е. как я понимаю в поле "стиль" должен появиться мой стиль MYSTYLE1, которому я уже выставлю нужные настройки. Например, есть же там встроенный стиль REGEXP, вот посмотреть как он устроен бы